# When submit is pressed, it auto scroll to the invalid text field or select option?

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling, autoscroll

When submit is pressed, it auto scroll to the invalid text field or select option?
I have try so many codes that similar to this but it's still can't scroll to the top smoothly, can someone explain to me more about this I really don't understand about this.

This is my whole code for the validation and jquery code at the bottom,I really don't know whats wrong.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create New Explore</title>    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desaru.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css" type="text/css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <?php include('header.html');  ?>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <div id="scrollbox">
    <!-- Content Section -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1><strong>Create New Explore</strong></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <br/><br/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { // website fully loaded
    $('#submit').click(function() { //if button id=submit click trigger function down
        var name = $('#foldername').val(); //retrieve input for folder name
        var httpvar = 'http://211.25.118.147';
        var defaultfolder = '/resource/';
        //alert(name); get retrieve test name 

        if(name==""){ // if foldername input blank
            alert("Insert folder name");
            }

        else {
            $.ajax( {
            url : "addfolder.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {foldername : name}, //pass input foldername = name(variable declare at the top) foldername name base on html that set
            success: function(result){ //if success will sent the post data
                //alert(result);

                if (result=="success") { //based on output echo addfolder.php

                    alert("File "+name+" has been added");

                    $("#SelectImageFolder option[value='.."+defaultfolder+name+"']").remove();

                    $("#SelectImageFolder").append($('<option>', { //add new options
                        value : ".."+defaultfolder+name ,
                        text : httpvar+defaultfolder+name
                        }))

                    $("#SelectImageFolder option:last").attr("selected", "selected");//auto select the last option

                    }

                else if(result=="fail") {// if the file exist then result will fail to create the file
                    alert("Something wrong happened");
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        }
        })
    });


</script>
<form action="CreateExploreProcess.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
            <!--<tr>
                <td>Class</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type='text' name='Class' readonly class='form-control' value='Explore' maxlength="20"/>
                </td>
            </tr>-->
            <!--<tr>
                <td>Placemark</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <Input type='number' name="Placemark" class='form-control' >
                </td>
            </tr>-->
            <tr>
                <td>Category</td>
                <td colspan="2">
           <div  class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
           <select id="categeory" required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Category..</option>
               <option value="Stay">Stay</option>
               <option value="Dining">Dining</option>
               <option value="Facilities">Facilities</option>
               <option value="ThingstoDo">Things to Do</option>
               <option value="NearbyAttractions">Nearby Attractions</option>
           </select>
           </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sub Category</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Sub Category...  </option>
               <option value="TheWestinDesaruCoastResort"> The Westin Desaru Coast Resort  </option>
               <option value="Kiosk"> Kiosk  </option>
               <option value="ShuttlePickupPoints"> Shuttle Pickup Points  </option>
               <option value="Rides&Attractions"> Rides & Attractions  </option>
               <option value="ParkingBay"> Parking Bay  </option>
               <option value="DesaruOstrichFarm"> Desaru Ostrich Farm  </option>
               <option value="Restroom"> Restroom  </option>
               <option value="Cafe"> Cafe  </option>
               <option value="AnataraCoastResort&Villas"> Anatara Coast Resort & Villas  </option>
               <option value="Kids"> Kids  </option>
               <option value="DesaruCrocodileFarm"> Desaru Crocodile Farm  </option>
               <option value="Restaurant"> Restaurant  </option>
               <option value="Riverside"> Riverside  </option>
               <option value="InformartionKiosk"> Informartion Kiosk  </option>
               <option value="Amphitheater"> Amphitheater  </option>
               <option value="MainAttractions"> Main Attractions  </option>
               <option value="DesaruCoastAdventureWaterPark"> Desaru Coast Adventure Water Park  </option>
               <option value="Golf"> Golf  </option>
               <option value="LuxuryResorts&Villas"> Luxury Resorts & Villas  </option>
               <option value="HardRockHotelDesaruCoast"> Hard Rock Hotel Desaru Coast  </option>
               <option value="ConferenceCentre"> Conference Centre  </option>
               <option value="Shopping"> Shopping  </option>
               <option value="Spas"> Spas  </option>
               <option value="BeachActivities"> Beach Activities  </option>
               <option value="DesaruFruitFarm"> Desaru Fruit Farm  </option>
               <option value="DisabledToilet"> Disabled Toilet  </option>
               <option value="FirstAid"> First Aid  </option>
               <option value="ChangingRoom"> Changing Room  </option>
               <option value="Locker"> Locker  </option>
               <option value="BabyChangingRoom"> Baby Changing Room  </option>
               <option value="LostandFound"> Lost and Found  </option>
               <option value="MuslimPrayerRoom"> Muslim Prayer Room  </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Item</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Item...  </option>
               <option value="Hotel"> Hotel </option>
               <option value="Kiosks"> Kiosks </option>
               <option value="ShuttlePickup"> Shuttle Pickup </option>
               <option value="Rides&Attractions"> Rides & Attractions </option>
               <option value="ParkingBay"> Parking Bay </option>
               <option value="Sightseeing"> Sightseeing </option>
               <option value="Restroom"> Restroom </option>
               <option value="Cafe"> Cafe </option>
               <option value="Kids"> Kids </option>
               <option value="Restaurant"> Restaurant </option>
               <option value="Riverside"> Riverside </option>
               <option value="InformartionKiosks"> Informartion Kiosks </option>
               <option value="Amphitheater"> Amphitheater </option>
               <option value="MainAttractions"> Main Attractions </option>
               <option value="DesaruCoastAdventureWaterPark"> Desaru Coast Adventure Water Park </option>
               <option value="Golf"> Golf </option>
               <option value="ConferenceCentre"> Conference Centre </option>
               <option value="Shopping"> Shopping </option>
               <option value="Spas"> Spas </option>
               <option value="BeachActivities"> Beach Activities </option>
               <option value="DisabledToilet"> Disabled Toilet </option>
               <option value="FirstAid"> First Aid </option>
               <option value="ChangingRoom"> Changing Room </option>
               <option value="Locker"> Locker </option>
               <option value="BabyChangingRoom"> Baby Changing Room </option>
               <option value="LostandFound"> Lost and Found </option>
               <option value="MuslimPrayerRoom"> Muslim Prayer Room </option>
               </select></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" id="title" required name='Title' class='form-control' maxlength="150"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Details Header</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" id="detailheader" required name="DetailsHeader" class='form-control' maxlength="200"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Details</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea required id="detail" name="Details" rows="8" class='form-control' maxlength="4000"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Button Promo</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <Input required type="text" name="ButtonPromo" class='form-control' maxlength="20"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Key Features</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <Input required type="text" name="KeyFeatures" class='form-control' maxlength="20"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Features</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea required name="FeaturesList" rows="5" class='form-control' maxlength="1000"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Image Folder</td>
                <td colspan="2"> 
                    <select name="SelectImageFolder" id="SelectImageFolder" class='form-control'>
                                  <option value="selected" selected="selected">Select a folder</option>
                                  <?php
                                        $dirs = glob("../resource/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

                                        // create variable constant url
                                        $httpvar = 'http://211.25.118.147';

                                        foreach($dirs as $val){
                                            $httpcon = str_replace("..",$httpvar,$val);
                                            echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$httpcon."</option>\n";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                    </select><br/>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" required name="foldername" id="foldername" placeholder="Folder Name" class='form-control' maxlength="100" />
                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button  type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn"/>Add Folder</button>
                 </span>
              </div></td>
              <script="js/script.js">
              </script>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>List Images</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileListImage" id="FileListImage">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 1</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input required type="file" name="FileCarousel1" id="FileCarousel1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 2</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel2" id="FileCarousel2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 3</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel3" id="FileCarousel3">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 4</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel4" id="FileCarousel4">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 5</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel5" id="FileCarousel5">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carousel 6</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="file" name="FileCarousel6" id="FileCarousel6">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Find On Map</td>
                <td colspan="2"> 
                    <Input required type="text" name="FindOnMap" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Call To Book</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <Input type="text" name="CallToBook" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!--<tr>
                <td>Find On Map Ico</td>
                <td> <input type="url" name="FindOnMapIco" class='form-control' /> </td>
                <td><input type="file" name="FileImage" id="FileImage"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Call To Book Ico</td>
                <td> <input type="url" name="CallToBookIco" class='form-control' /></td>
                <td><input type="file" name="FileImage" id="FileImage"></td>
            </tr>-->
            <tr>
             <!--<td >Icon</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="url" name="Icon" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>-->
            <tr>
                <td>In Park</td>
                <td colspan="2">
             <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select...  </option>
               <option value="Yes"> Yes  </option>
               <option value="No"> No  </option>
               <option value="">   </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ticket Entry</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" name="TicketedEntry" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Operation Hours</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea name="OperationHours" rows="6" class='form-control'> </textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ride Details</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea name="RideDetails" class='form-control' maxlength="255"/></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Listing Details</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <textarea name="ListingDetails" class='form-control' maxlength="255"/></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!--<td>Favourites</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select...  </option>
               <option value="Yes"> Yes  </option>
               <option value="">  </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FB Like</td>
                <td colspan="2">
             <div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
             <select>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select...  </option>
               <option value="Yes"> Yes  </option>
               <option value="">   </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>-->
            <tr>
                <td>More Details</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" id="moredetail" name="MoreDetails" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Distance </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" id="distance" name="DistanceAway" class='form-control' maxlength="100"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div id="status" class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
           <select required>
               <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Status...  </option>
               <option value="Active"> Active  </option>
               <option value="Inactive"> Inactive  </option>
             </select>
             </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zoom</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="start" name="ZoomStart" class='form-control' placeholder="Start" min="14" max="19"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="end" name="ZoomEnd" class='form-control' placeholder="End" min="14" max="19"/>
                </td>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>GPS Coordinate</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Lat" name="Lat" class='form-control' placeholder="Latitude" maxlength="12"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Lng" name="numeric" class='form-control' placeholder="Longitude" maxlength="12"/>
                </td>
            </td>
            <script src="js/script.js">
            </script>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                <input required type="text" id="hpno" name="Phone" class='form-control' maxlength="12"/>
                </td>
                <script src="js/script.js">
                </script>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
              <td colspan="2">
                    <input type='submit' id='submit' name='Add' value='Save' class='btn btn-warning'/>
                  <a href='Explore.php' class='btn btn-danger'>Back</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <span id="error_message" class="text-danger"></span>
            <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span>
        </table>
</form>
  <!-- End Content Section -->
  <?php  include('footer.html');  ?>
    </div> </div>
<script>
$('#submit').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 1000);
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js.fiddle

[https://jsfiddle.net/xgy3uqm0/](http://jsfiddle.net/xgy3uqm0/)

Comment: Make a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xgy3uqm0/

Answer (score 0):

```
html,
body{
    overflow: visible;
}
```

put it in your .css file then check.

Comment: kindly share your proper code so we can understand easily.

Comment: try to put your script tag before footer.

Comment: I have ady try but still the same